# How to cloak directories in TFS command line

Tags: command-line, tfs, workspace

I want to ignore some directory while checking out code from TFS using TFS command line.

For example, say i have a TFS url path where i have two directory, namely **Iteration9** and **Iteration11**  .

Now I want to check out from that url path such a way so that only **Iteration9** gets checked out and ignore the **Iteration11**

So far i am following the steps,

Create a workspace named cloak_1:

> ./tf workspace -new -collection:http://tfsna.int.com:8080/tfs/C_Collection -login:user27@domain,password cloak_1;

Cloak the **Iteration11** directory which i don't want:

> ./tf workfold -cloak $/Cobalt Search/Releases/1.0/Iteration11 -workspace:cloak_1 -login:user27@domain,'password';

Map the path to my local Directory:

> ./tf workfold -map -workspace:cloak_1 -login:user27@domain,password '$/C_Search/Releases/1.0' /tfs/TEE-CLC-10.1.0/cl-test1;

Finally get the source code:

> ./tf get -recursive -login:user27@domain,password /tfs/TEE-CLC-10.1.0/cl-test1;

But the cloak is not working here. i am getting both the directory in my local folder. please tell me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: If you could show a screenshot of your workspace configuration in vs that would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the workspace configuration that your want in visual studio with the UI and then clone it when you want to use it.

http://roadtoalm.com/2011/10/25/hidden-gems-in-tfspart-6-managing-workspaces-in-tfs-with-workspace-templates/